# Preventing page curl from curling offscreen views

Tags: ios

I have a navigation controller based application I am working on.  It uses iAd to display adds.  When the AdBannerView has no add (based on `bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:`), the banner view is slid off of the bottom of the screen.

There is another view which is shown from the root view controller using the modal page curl transition.  When the banner view is on screen, there are no issues with the transition.  However, when it is off screen, a blank, banner view-sized box is appended to the bottom of the curled page.

I have tried setting just about every view controller's view and the apps window to have `clipsToBounds` set to `TRUE` to avail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the banner view's `alpha` to `0` after it is animated offscreen.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^
{
    //Move banner offscreen
} completion:^(BOOL finished)
{
    banner.alpha = 0;
}];
```

<sub>Typed on mobile, don't ship without testing</sub>

Sometimes the best solution is the simplest one.